# display a website currently visited on system log tplink

Tags: networking, router

I was looking for a way to display current websites visited by other users on system log tab of tplink router.

As i've trid so far, i couldn't find any options available for that. 
Here's what i got in Log Content:

```
DHCPS:Recv INFORM from 38:59:F9:B3:C4:49
DHCPS:Recv INFORM from 2C:D0:5A:C0:B0:25
DHCPS:Send ACK to 192.168.0.101
....
```

Can't it display a website instead of this above ?

Answer (score 0):

Tp-Link router can't display a website currently visited on system log.
If you want to track lan users visited sites you have to bye a router that can show visited by lan users.

> For Example: Linksys